# WebClient with download URL from firebase gets bad request

Tags: c#, .net, google-cloud-firestore, webclient, revit-api

I'm using Firebase as a DB (with Realtime Database) and I wanted to use Firebase storage as well for my files.
I can get the download URL easily but when it comes to download the file from the URL using WebClient I get an error 400 Bad Request.
The exact error :

```
"error": {
"code": 400,
"message": "Invalid HTTP method/URL pair."
}
```

My program is a .NET 4.8 class library used by Revit API
The weird thing is : when I use the exact same code inside a console application (.NET 4.8 as well) the sample works fine and the file is downloaded.
My code :

```
static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        using (WebClient client = new WebClient())
        {
            var desktop = Environment.GetFolderPath(Environment.SpecialFolder.Desktop);
            string fileName = desktop + "\\projectinformations.png";
            client.DownloadFile(
                new Uri(@"https://firebasestorage.googleapis.com/v0/b/PROJECT_NAME/o/Plugins%2FProd%2Fprojectinformations.png?alt=media&token=b7c41dca-96cf-4997-ab70-a61e05843ee4"),
                fileName);
            Console.ReadLine();
        }
    }
```

However the exact same sample inside my class library will fail with the error above. Have you got any clues ?
Any help is appreciated !

Comment: That error usually means that there is something wrong in the URI generated, can you try logging the value of the URI to be sure it is as expected?

Comment: How are you using this part of the code inside the class library for Revit?

Comment: @RafaelLemos The URI is perfectly fine it works inside a browser even in private navigation. And as I say the download works within the console app but not within the revit api class library.

Comment: @MostafaTarekYassien The sample I submit is from the console app. However using the same code (except for the static void main part) inside the revit api context doesn't work.

Comment: That is why I'm asking, Revit API Usually does some weird things when trying to use other services.

Comment: @MostafaTarekYassien well I have no problems using the firebase realtime database. Inside an other project I was downloading files using webclient but the files were hosted in out homemade server and not firestorage